# $.post(url, function(data,status) {alert(data)}); alert() not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, post, httpresponse

I have a Rails app, which communicates with other rails app for data insertion. Am using jQuery `$.post` method for data insertion. For insertion my other Rails app shows `200 OK`. But in post method's function alert doesn't show anything.

jQuery code:

```
$.post("http://localhost:3000/persons.json",
    { 
        person: 
        { 
            id: $("#id").val(), 
            name: $("#name").val(), 
        } 
    },function(data, status){
        alert("Hello World!!");
        alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
    });
```

Controller code in other Rails App:

```
p = Person.new(a_params)
if p.save
    notice = "Person data entered successfully"
    render json: notice, status: 200
end
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Chain on a `fail` and see what fails ?

Comment: any errors on the browser's console ?

Comment: `person: { id: $("#id").val(), name: $("#name").val() }` will be converted to `person%5Bid%5D=1&person%5Bname%5D=2`. Are you sure you want params to look this way?

Comment: No errors in the console.

Comment: insertion is happening correctly. I checked the database for insertion.

Comment: @adeneo how do I do that? Chaining on `fail`?

Comment: `json: notice` looks suspicious to me (I don't "do" Ruby or Rails), because a JSON document's top level must be an object or an array, not just a string. Some JSON parsers allow you to serialize and deserialize fragments, but if the response to an ajax post is going to be `application/json`, it has to have a top level object or array.

Comment: `var $post = $.post(//blah blah blah)` then `$post.done(function(){ //successful}).fail(function(){ alert("errorino")});`

Comment: Also, the datatype expected back is going to be `text/html` in the closing `})` you should probably do `}, 'json');`

Comment: @Ohgodwhy: It is getting into `fail function`.

Comment: Check the network tab in your web inspector. What is the real response? Also, You can use `chrome://net-internals/#events` as a URL in your browser to see deeper into the request, maybe there's some redirect issue or something.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy Am getting `200 Ok` for `POST` method in network tab.

Comment: And what does it say is the return result?

Comment: @Ohgodwhy Am using chrome in `chrome disable same origin policy` mode. Does that matter? And how to get the error message in `fail` method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not returning a proper JSON object as response, so jQuery interprets the response as `error` instead of `success`.

You might want to try this:

```
p = Person.new(a_params)
if p.save
  notice = "Person data entered successfully"
  render json: {notice: notice, status: 200} # This ruby Hash is returned as a JSON object
end
```

Then in your jQuery code you can access `data['notice']` and `data['status']`.